# Determine truth value of following,

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Determine truth value of following:

$(1)\;\forall x P(x)$

$(2)\;\exists x Q(x)$

$(3)\;\forall x\, \exists y\;R(x,y)$

$(4)\;\exists x \,\forall y\;R(x, y)$

$(5)\;\forall x\,(\lnot Q(x))$

---

For $x, y \in \mathbb Z^+$, (meaning $x, y$ are positive integers):

Let $P(x): x$ is even; $\quad\;Q(x): x$ is a prime number; $\quad \;R(x, y): x+y$ is even.

---

My Understanding:
p(x) = 2,4,8,10 q(x) = 3,7,11,13,17 not sure on r(x) Ans: i. false as x is all postive integers and all are not even ii. true. atleast one x which is prime iii. 
iv.
 v.False. x are set of postive integers, negation of p(x) is odd integers

Comment: Why don't you start us off with an idea you have about the **four** separate questions.  Most of us would be happy to confirm, or correct any misstep you might make.  But you need to be as active as any helper is with the aim you are able to answer these questions.

Comment: p(x) = 2,4,8,10
q(x) = 3,7,11,13,17
not sure on r(x)

Ans:
i. false as x is all postive integers and all are not even
ii. true. atleast one x which is prime
iii.
iv.
v. False. x are set of postive integers, negation of p(x) is odd integers

@amWhy

Comment: What big set does x belong to, in general?

Comment: sorry, x what ?

Comment: $x$ must be an element in some set like the natural numbers, or at least $x\in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18\}$, from which you can determine whether all are even, or whether their exists an x that is prime...

Comment: as you can see, x&y both represent positive integers

Comment: Is it true that for all x \in the integers,  $P(x)$ is true?  No, because for $x= 3$, $P(x)$ is not true.  So it is **not true that** $\forall x(P(x))$.  However, we can say that in the set of integers, there exist some $x$ that is prime. Specifically, we know that $\exists x(Q(x))$, by pointing to $x=7$, since $Q(7)$ is true. etc

Comment: Nice work, Somesh! I think you understand more than you think you do. You did fine, once you started expressing yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x, y \in \mathbb N$.

Let $P(x)$ denote "$x$ is even."

Let $Q(x)$ denote "$x$ is prime."

Let $R(x, y)$ denote "$x+y$ is even".

Now, clearly, we know that not all integers are even. Hence $\lnot\forall x (P(x))$.  That is $\forall x (P(x))$ is false.

We know that there are many prime numbers in the integers.  Example: For $x=7\in \mathbb Z, Q(7)$ is true. That means that $\exists x Q(x)$ is true.

(3) It is true that  $$\forall x \exists y (R(x, y)).$$
for every integer $x$, there is some integer $y$ such that $x+y$ is positive. For all even $x$  choose y to be any even number and we have $R(x, y)$ is true.  Similarly, for all odd $x$, there is some odd y, so that $x+y$ is odd + odd = even, and therefore true.

The next two questions evaluate to false.

$\exists x \forall y R(x, y)$ is false.

$\forall x(\lnot Q(x)) \equiv \lnot \exists x(Q(x))$ is false

---

In summary $(1)\;F\;\; (2)\;T\;\; (3)\;T\;\; (4)\;F\;\; (5)\;F\;\;$